# How to get mysql query last five week of current day

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

> My table structure is like this:

**Column Name:**

```
id
name
start_date
end_date
```

> **Example:** today day is "Wednesday" so i want to get last five week's Wednesday data, with check between start_date and end_date
>
> please check current day wise data

Comment: So... What have you tried? Look at `date()`, `strtotime('last Wednesday', time())`

Comment: SELECT *,WEEKDAY(created_date) as weekdays
FROM user
WHERE created_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date ORDER BY start_date ASC LIMIT 5

Comment: What’s created_date? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Write below line in where condition

```
WHERE created_date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY);
```

Comment: there is no use created_date

Answer (score 0):

First with PHP code get last 5 days of current day then pass those days in sql query

```
<?php
function last_days($total)
{
    $days= array();
    $today = date("l");
    for($i = 1; $i<= $total;$i++)
    {
        $days[] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-$i $today"));     
    }
    return $days;
}
$days = last_days(5);
//print_r($days);
$days_str = "'".implode("','", $days)."'";
$query = "SELECT *,WEEKDAY(created_date) as weekdays FROM user WHERE created_date IN ($days_str) ORDER BY start_date ASC";
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/TlYGA)